# Import XML data using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have got an excel file which happens to be an XML table, I have saved it as an xml file instead and whilst trying to use powershell to import it to a SQL database. It is coming up with blank values.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <RecordsExport xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <RecordsExport>
     <ResultSet>
       <SRN>1</SRN>
       <Name>Tom</Name>
       <Gender>Male</Gender>
       <ChangeDate xsi:nil="true" />
    </ResultSet>
    <ResultSet>
      <SRN>2</SRN>
      <Name>Jack</Name>
      <Gender>Male</Gender>
      <ChangeDate xsi:nil="true" />
    </ResultSet>
  </RecordsExport>
</RecordsExport>
```

Powershell code

```
$xmldata = Get-Content -Path 'C:\temp\test.xml'
 $import_data = foreach ($data in $xmldata.RecordsExport.ResultSet){
    
 [PSCustomObject]@{
     SRN = $data.SRN
     Name= $data.Name
     Gender = $data.Gender
     ChangeDate = $data.ChangeDate
 }
    
 }
```

Comment: `Get-Content` returns an array of strings, you need to convert it to an xml document somehow before you can treat it as such. `$xmldata = ...` -> `[xml]$xmldata = ...` should do the trick

Comment: @user3535468, don't forget to mark an answer for other user that have the same prob as you :)

Comment: cannot `Import-clixml` do this better?

Answer (score 3):

Simply,

```
$xml_file = get-content "C:\TEMP\test.xml"
$xml_file = [xml]$xml_file
```

Then, example in your case :

```
$xml_file.RecordsExport.ResultSet
```

To print Result Set.

Answer (score 0):

```
[xml]$xml_file = get-content "C:\TEMP\test.xml"
```